# enable dictionaries in dictionary app under el capitan

Tags: macos, dictionary, language

os x el capitan, new mac book air with fresh os x installation.

In dictionary app preferences, no foreign language dictionaries appear in the the list of available dictionaries.   However, in /Library/Dictionaries there are many available dictionaries.

How can I access these dictionaries?

Comment: Try setting up a new user account and see if you have the same problem when logged into that.  If not, sounds like a broken .plist in Home/Library/Preferences or something similar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to `Dictionary > Preferences`. That will bring up a window like this:

[image: Dictionary preferences pane]

Then, check them off and they will appear on the Dictionary front-page.

Comment: I see only the first 4 entries in Dictionary-> preferences.   I cannot find any com.apple.Dictionary.plist file on my system at all.

Answer (score 1):

This was silly.  I just had to resize the preferences window to reveal the other dictionaries!

Comment: This. I can't believe I just lost 45 minutes to this.